# Xamarin.iOS app fails to compile in Visual Studio for Mac 8.10.14

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I have the following error when compiling an Xamarin iOS app in Visual Studio for Mac 8.10.14 when doing it in Release Mode to Generic Device:

```
MTOUCH : error : System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
    Parameter name: index
      at System.Collections.CollectionBase.System.Collections.IList.get_Item (System.Int32 index) [0x0000d] in <92218043474744ea9d64d27064c35dcb>:0 
      at Mono.Cecil.GenericParameterCollection.get_Item (System.Int32 index) [0x00006] in <af3d3de500394ed18df77e27b5623689>:0 
      at Mono.Cecil.ReflectionReader.GetTypeRefFromSig (Mono.Cecil.Signatures.SigType t, Mono.Cecil.GenericContext context) [0x002ee] in <af3d3de500394ed18df77e27b5623689>:0 
      at Mono.Cecil.ReflectionReader.GetGenericArg (Mono.Cecil.Signatures.GenericArg arg, Mono.Cecil.GenericContext context) [0x00000] in <af3d3de500394ed18df77e27b5623689>:0 
      at Mono.Cecil.ReflectionReader.GetTypeRefFromSig (Mono.Cecil.Signatures.SigType t, Mono.Cecil.GenericContext context) [0x003aa] in <af3d3de500394ed18df77e27b5623689>:0 
      at Mono.Cecil.ReflectionReader.CreateTypeSpecFromSig (Mono.Cecil.Signatures.TypeSpec ts, System.Int32 index, Mono.Cecil.GenericContext context) [0x00000] in <af3d3de500394ed18df77e27b5623689>:0 
      at Mono.Cecil.ReflectionReader.GetTypeSpecAt (System.UInt32 rid, Mono.Cecil.GenericContext context) [0x00049] in <af3d3de500394ed18df77e27b5623689>:0 
      at Mono.Cecil.ReflectionReader.GetTypeDefOrRef (Mono.Cecil.Metadata.MetadataToken token, Mono.Cecil.GenericContext context) [0x00051] in <af3d3de500394ed18df77e27b5623689>:0 
      at Mono.Cecil.ReflectionReader.GetMemberRefAt (System.UInt32 rid, Mono.Cecil.GenericContext context) [0x000a1] in <af3d3de500394ed18df77e27b5623689>:0 
      at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.ReadCilBody (Mono.Cecil.Cil.MethodBody body, System.IO.BinaryReader br) [0x00430] in <af3d3de500394ed18df77e27b5623689>:0 
      at Mono.Cecil.Cil.CodeReader.VisitMethodBody (Mono.Cecil.Cil.MethodBody body) [0x000c0] in <af3d3de500394ed18df77e27b5623689>:0 
      at Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition.LoadBody () [0x00058] in <af3d3de500394ed18df77e27b5623689>:0 
      at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.FullLoad () [0x00047] in <af3d3de500394ed18df77e27b5623689>:0 
      at Mono.CilStripper.AssemblyStripper.FullLoad () [0x0000b] in <af3d3de500394ed18df77e27b5623689>:0 
      at Mono.CilStripper.AssemblyStripper.Strip () [0x00000] in <af3d3de500394ed18df77e27b5623689>:0 
      at Mono.CilStripper.AssemblyStripper.StripAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly, System.String file) [0x00016] in <af3d3de500394ed18df77e27b5623689>:0 
      at Mono.CilStripper.Program.StripAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly, System.String output) [0x00000] in <af3d3de500394ed18df77e27b5623689>:0 
      at Mono.CilStripper.Program.Main (System.String[] arguments) [0x00064] in <af3d3de500394ed18df77e27b5623689>:0 
    
    MTOUCH : error MT1009: Could not copy the assembly '/Users/.../Documents/repo/test/test/test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache/3-Build/test.dll' to '/Users/.../Documents/repo/test/test/test.iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/test.iOS.app/test.dll': Could not strip assembly `/Users/.../Documents/repo/test/test/test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache/3-Build/test.dll`.
            
        Could not strip assembly `/Users/.../Documents/repo/test/test/test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache/3-Build/test.dll`.
        Could not strip assembly `/Users/.../Documents/repo/test/test/test.iOS/obj/iPhone/Release/mtouch-cache/3-Build/test.dll`.
```

It seems a problem with mono sdk, but I can't figured out how to fix this...

My current Visual Studio for Mac installation is:

```
Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac
Version 8.10.14 (build 17)
Installation UUID: 18219619-f9f8-414d-9e88-cd653673a349
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    Xamarin.Mac 6.18.0.23 (d16-6 / 088c73638)
    Package version: 612000140

Mono Framework MDK
Runtime:
    Mono 6.12.0.140 (2020-02/51d876a041e) (64-bit)
    Package version: 612000140

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 13.1 (19466)
Build 13A1030d

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 15.2.0.17 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 738fde344
Branch: xcode13.1
Build date: 2021-11-09 02:45:16-0500

Operating System
Mac OS X 12.0.1
Darwin 21.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.1.0
    Wed Oct 13 17:33:24 PDT 2021
    root:xnu-8019.41.5~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 x86_64
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check in your source to your repository (because the next step is a major delete -- done correctly it won't delete any source, but best to be safe.) Close Visual Studio.  Delete all bin and obj folders within your solution. That gets you to a clean state - even cleaner than doing "Clean Solution". On Windows, in its File Explorer, I would use `name:=bin` in the solution folder, to find all bin folders (and nothing else). Not sure what the Mac Finder equivalent is. Maybe even reboot the Mac, just to be sure nothing strange is happening anywhere.

Comment: Another approach to this, is to check out sources from your repository, to a new folder. This guarantees there is nothing strange anywhere. Build there. If that works, then delete the old folder, rename the new one to the folder name you usually use.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve i tried deleting bin and obj folder, also clone repository (which don't have that folders), but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: That's puzzling. Could you be running low on disk space? OR As a temporary workaround, try different "linker" options?  So you can get a build, even if it isn't as small as it should be?

Comment: Search in Build Output starting from the top. Any “error” lines earlier in file? Are you able to make a Release build of other projects? (If you don’t have others, Make a new solution, pick any xamarin project type, build that new project, can you make a release build? If necessary, copy your info.plist to it - pretend it is your app.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve testing a new project and adding some features of original project, I found the problem, it was a custom control element with a generic type, which is defined in xaml <Controls:Picker x:TypeArguments="Model:TipoObservacion"/> is working in debug mode but not in release

Comment: Excellent that you identified it! Can you fix by changing that control so is not generic? Maybe that isn’t supported well.